# Sum of Oscillating Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to find the sum of series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(-1)^n$ ?

Further prove that the series oscillates finitely.

Comment: Please read the FAQ for this site. Specifically, you may want to read up on [how to ask homework questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots$. Differentiate. We get $-\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}=-1+2x-3x^2+4x^3-\cdots$. Put $x=1$. We get that our sum is $-\frac{1}{4}$. Just kidding! Kind of. You may want to read about Abel summation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s a series, not a sequence. Since the terms of the series do not converge to $0$, the series diverges. For the second question, I assume that you’re talking about the sequence of partial sums. Calculate the first few values: $-1$;$-1+2=1$; $-1+2-3=1-3=-2$; $-2+4=2$; $2-5=-3$; $-3+6=3$; $3-7=-4$; and $-4+8=4$. By this point you should realize that the oscillations are getting bigger without bound. You might even be able to conjecture that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{2m}n(-1)^n=m\;,$$

in which case you could try to prove this by induction on $m$.

Answer (score 2):

The sum you've given is divergent (the terms of the series do not tend to $0$), and the oscillations grow arbitrarily large. So the sum doesn't exist, and the second claim isn't true.